# Como pasar el valor del entry que hay en una funcion a otra funcion diferente en python?

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy intentando usar obtener un valor de un entry que existe en una funcion (ventana de tkinter con root) a otra funcion que es donde se llegara con un boton de enviar usando command.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.title('Nutricion y salud')
root.geometry("200x200+290+120")

lbltitle = Label(root, text="Nutricion y Salud")
lbltitle.place(x=50, y=20)

def registrarse():
    def enviar1():
        print("Enviado usuario: ",var_nombres.get()) #Aqui deberia llegar el valor del entry pero llega vacio siempre

    print("Registrando...")
    root2 = Tk()
    root2.title('Registrando')
    root2.geometry("400x500+500+120")

    lblFname = Label(root2, text="Nombres")
    lblFname.place(x=45, y=50)
    var_nombres = StringVar()
    txtFname = Entry(root2, textvariable=var_nombres)
    txtFname.place(height=20, width=130, x=45, y=70)

    btEnviar1 = Button(root2, text="Enviar", command=enviar1)
    btEnviar1.place(x=45, y=300)
    root2.mainloop()

btReg = Button(root, text="Registrarse", command = registrarse)
btReg.place(x=70, y=65)

root.mainloop()
```

Intente pasarle como argumento desde el commando usando un lambda pero tampoco obtuve resultado, tampoco sirve si defino la variable afuera de las funciones

Comment: Por favor adjunta solo el código relevante y sé más específico con tu duda/problema

Comment: La pregunta como tal es como puedo obtener el valor de la variable que almacena la informacion del entry como en el ejemplo se llama (var_nombres) y la quiero imprimir en la otra funcion llamada enviar1 pero no imprime nada, es decir no capta ese valor porque esta en otra funcion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

prueba cambiando tu segunda ventana por una `Toplevel` y borrale el mainloop() que esta en la funcion registrarse, y debe funcionarte.

de esta forma debe quedarte:

```
def registrarse():
   def enviar1():
      print("Enviado usuario:",var_nombres.get())

   print("Registrando...")
   root2 = Toplevel()
   root2.title('Registrando')
   root2.geometry("400x500+500+120")

   lblFname = Label(root2, text="Nombres")
   lblFname.place(x=45, y=50)
   var_nombres = StringVar()
   txtFname = Entry(root2, textvariable=var_nombres)
   txtFname.place(height=20, width=130, x=45, y=70)

   btEnviar1 = Button(root2, text="Enviar", command=enviar1)
   btEnviar1.place(x=45, y=300)
```

Comment: Si funciona muchas gracias !